# What are the necessary and sufficient properties for a function to be called a RNG?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

So we want to write a function that generates random numbers in the range 1-5. Lets say we come up with a function rand5() that we believe does this. I am a bit skeptical around the properties this function should satisfy. For what I know is, the probability of every outcome (here 1,2,3,4,5) should be equal and the every outcome should be independent of previous outcomes.

The doubt I have is - Is it also required that the probability of each outcome should be 1/N where N is the cardinality of set of outcomes (here 5)?

Comment: This isn't really a question about math, but about computer science. There are a number of known and established tests one can do, for instance the [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) or the [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) library.

Comment: I stumbled across https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13/rand5-to-rand7 and from there I got this confusion. In the answers given is the resultant function atleast a PRNG? Because although the probability of getting a number from 1-7 is equal = 3/25 it is not 1/7. Is there a requirement as such? Also the sum of all probabilities would be 21/25 and not 1.

Comment: Probabilities should always add up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question in the OP comment (how to convert the PRG generating numbers 1..5 into the PRG generating numbers 1..7):

The algorithm used in [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13/rand5-to-rand7) boils down to

```
repeat
  x:= rand5()+5*rand5()-5;
until x<8;
return(x);
```

The expression `rand5()+5*rand5()-5` generates numbers $1..25$ with equal probability $1/25$. The `repeat-until` loop implements conditioning on $x<8$, and in the conditional model the only possible numbers are $1..7$, generated with equal probability $1/7$.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally expected that all outcomes of an RNG be equally probable unless specified otherwise.  There are RNGs that supply normally distributed random numbers, for example.  We usually ask for more, like the lack of sequential correlation.  As you demand more "randomness" the numbers get more expensive to create, so some applications accept a "quick and dirty" approach that may have some detectable correlations.